# How do I close a resource after responding using JAX-RS's CompletionStage async processing?

Tags: jax-rs, jersey-2.0, completable-future

JAX-RS AsyncResponse's CompletionCallback and ConnectionCallback allow for the cleanup of resources after a response is completed or dropped.

```java
@GET
public void get(@Suspend AsyncResponse response) {
  executor.submit(() -> {
    CloseableHttpResponse httpResponse = getHttpResponse();
    response.register(closeOnCompleteOrDisconnect(httpResponse));
    response.resume(Response.ok().entity(httpResponse.getEntity().getContent()).build());
    // We couldn't close the httpResponse now because the entity content hasn't been read.
    // it can't be closed till the message body writer finishes streaming the response.
    // hence the closeOnCompleteOrDisconnect callback.
  });
}
```

I'd like to convert this code to CompletableFuture, but don't know how to close the httpResponse after the message body has been written.

```
@GET
public CompletableFuture<Response> getAsync() {
  return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
    CloseableHttpResponse httpResponse = getHttpResponse();
    Response.ok().entity(httpResponse.getEntity().getContent()).build();
    // still can't close the httpResponse, and now we've no AsyncResponse to register a callback on.
  }, executor);
  
}
```

https://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/jaxrs-2_1-final-eval-spec/jaxrs-2_1-final-spec.pdf?AuthParam=1605738947_546c3c96f63881e7441d4b95f55d00e7

Comment: I don't get it. Why can't you call `response.register(closeOnCompleteOrDisconnect(httpResponse));` in `supplyAsync`?

Comment: `getAsync` doesn't have AsyncResponse parameter, normally a CompletableFuture resource method doesn't need AsyncResponse. I guess I could include a AsyncResponse parameter. Would it need the @Suspend annotation? Would it confuse Jersey?

Comment: did you try any of the questions you have above?

Comment: I'd rather an answer based on documentation or specification than experimentation. Experimentally `CompletableFuture` with `@Suspend AsyncResponse`  causes 500's while `CompletableFuture` with `@Context` appears to work.